# Yii2 Gridview didn't show data in Index page

Tags: gridview, yii2, dataprovider

I'm using Model Search to filter and query all data into controller and send back data into View. The query is fine, but in View can't show data. And I don't know how to fix it?

This is my Model search:

```
$user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;

$subquery = Workload::find()->select(['p.id', 'p.project_name', 'w.user_id', 'w.commit_time', 'w.comment', 'w.workload_type'])
    ->from(['project as p', 'workload as w'])
    ->where(['and','w.user_id = '.$user_id, 'p.id = w.project_id']);

$query = Workload::find()
    ->select(['workloadTeam.project_id', 'wp.project_name', 'workloadTeam.user_id', 'workloadTeam.commit_time', 'workloadTeam.week','workloadTeam.workload_type', 'workloadTeam.comment'])
    ->from(['wp' => $subquery]);

$query->join('INNER JOIN', 'workload as workloadTeam', 'wp.id = workloadTeam.project_id')->all();

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
     'query' => $query,
]);
```

In my Controller:

```
    public function actionIndex()
        {
            $searchModel = new WorkloadSearch();
            $dataProvider = $searchModel->searchWorkloadofUser(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

            return $this->render('index', [
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
        }
```

And in my View Index page:

```
$gridColumns = [
    [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
        'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width: 40px;']
    ],
    [
        'attribute' => 'user_id',
        'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Members Alias'),
        'value' => 'profile.full_name',
        'filter' => \app\modules\admin\models\User::profileDropDown(),
        'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width: 150px;', 'class' => 'select2'],
        'filterOptions' => ['data-widget' => 'select2'],
        'format' => 'html',
    ],
    [
        'attribute' => 'project_id',
        'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Assigned Projects'),
        'value' => 'project.project_name',
        'filter' => \app\modules\admin\models\Project::projectWorkloadMemberDropdown(),
        'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width: 150px;', 'class' => 'select2', 'placeholder' => 'Select your projects'],
        'filterOptions' => ['data-widget' => 'select2'],
        'format' => 'html',
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Committed (hr.)',
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return $model->commit_time;
        }
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Burned Amount (hr.)',
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return WorkLog::getTotalBurnedHoursofUser($model->user_id, $model->project_id);
        },
    ],
    [
        'attribute' => 'week',
        'filterInputOptions' => ['class' => 'form-control datepicker'],
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return $model->week;
        },
        'label' => Yii::t('app', 'From Date'),
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Comment',
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return $model->comment;
        }
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Workload Type',
//        'attribute' => 'workload_type',
        'filter' => \app\modules\admin\models\Workload::WorkloadTypeDropdownList(),
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return \app\modules\admin\models\Workload::$workload_type_label[$model->workload_type];
        }
    ]
];
?>

<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => $gridColumns,
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't show data"? There is no GridView at all or it shows 0 records? Also please provide full code of displaying GridView in the view.

Comment: I mean didn't show data, but the query is query good. The view page show nomally without data

Comment: Please add the rest of the code for displaying GridView.

Comment: This is the link for full code of View page: http://pastebin.com/fWiemhDr

Comment: It's better to add code right to the answer rather than posting it at external resources, especially when it's not so long. But I can see now that GridView is displayed normally (at first I thought maybe you forgot `echo`), so the problem is related with 0 records. I recommend to check generated query and compare it to desired. Use debug console for it.

Comment: Like I said before, view page show normally, but data from database that I query can't show in gridview of view page.

I've checked query statement, this show fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i've found in your code that you are using `all()` method which is not required by `ActiveDataProvider` because `all()` method returns all the rows but you need to pass query object to `ActiveDataProvider`

```
$user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;

$subquery = Workload::find()->select(['p.id', 'p.project_name', 'w.user_id', 'w.commit_time', 'w.comment', 'w.workload_type'])
    ->from(['project as p', 'workload as w'])
    ->where(['and','w.user_id = '.$user_id, 'p.id = w.project_id']);

$query = Workload::find()
    ->select(['workloadTeam.project_id', 'wp.project_name', 'workloadTeam.user_id', 'workloadTeam.commit_time', 'workloadTeam.week','workloadTeam.workload_type', 'workloadTeam.comment'])
    ->from(['wp' => $subquery]);

$query->join('INNER JOIN', 'workload as workloadTeam', 'wp.id = workloadTeam.project_id');

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
     'query' => $query,
]);
```

After that you can print `$dataProvider->models` for debugging purpose that you are getting rows from database. If you are getting rows means you are now can pass `$dataProvider` object to `GridView`.

Comment: I've removed `all()` function and print `$dataprovider->models` and I felt good, but  when I pass to `$dataProvider` in Index, it don't show data. I don't understand how?